# Transformations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, transform

I'm trying to draw objects (lines/patches) with a fixed size (in device coordinates) at a certain position (in data coordinates). This behavior is akin to markers and the tips of annotation arrows, both of which are (size-) invariant under zoom and pan.

Why does the following example not work as expected?

The expected output is two crossed lines forming the diagonals of a 50x50 point square (device coordinates). The left lower corner of said square should be at point (1,0) in data coordinates.
While the computed points appear to be correct, the second diagonal is simply not visible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
import matplotlib as mpl

import numpy as np


class FixedPointOffsetTransform(mtrans.Transform):
    """
    Always returns the same transformed point plus
    the given point in device coordinates as an offset.
    """
    def __init__(self, trans, fixed_point):
        mtrans.Transform.__init__(self)
        self.input_dims = self.output_dims = 2
        self.has_inverse = False
        self.trans = trans
        self.fixed_point = np.array(fixed_point).reshape(1, 2)

    def transform(self, values):
        fp = self.trans.transform(self.fixed_point)
        values = np.array(values)
        if values.ndim == 1:
            return fp.flatten() + values
        else:
            return fp + values


fig , ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlim([-1,10])
ax.set_ylim([-1,10])

# this transformation shifts the input by the given offset
#   the offset is transformed with the given transformation
#   and then added to the input
fixed_pt_trans = FixedPointOffsetTransform(ax.transData, (1, 0))


# these values are in device coordinates i.e. points
height = 50
width = 50

# two points in device coordinates, that are modified with the above transformation
A = fixed_pt_trans.transform((0,0))
B = fixed_pt_trans.transform((width,height))

l1 = mpl.lines.Line2D([A[0],B[0]], [A[1],B[1]])
ax.add_line(l1)
# already in device coordinates with the offset applied,
#   no further transformation nessesary
l1.set_transform(None)

print(A)
print(B)
print(l1.get_transform().transform(A))
print(l1.get_transform().transform(B))

# two points in device coordinates (unmodified)
A = (width,0)
B = (0,height)
l2 = mpl.lines.Line2D([A[0],B[0]], [A[1],B[1]])
ax.add_line(l2)
# apply transformation to add offset
l2.set_transform(fixed_pt_trans)

print(l2.get_transform().transform(A))
print(l2.get_transform().transform(B))


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to matplotlib [API Changes](http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#api-changes) documentation, starting with [matplotlib 1.2.x](http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#changes-in-1-2-x):

> Transform subclassing behaviour is now subtly changed. If your transform implements a non-affine transformation, then it should override the `transform_non_affine` method, rather than the generic `transform` method.

Therefore, simply reimplementing the `transform_non_affine` instead of the `transform` method, as said above, in the `FixedPointOffsetTransform` class seems to solve the issue:

```
class FixedPointOffsetTransform(mtrans.Transform):
"""
Always returns the same transformed point plus
the given point in device coordinates as an offset.
"""
def __init__(self, trans, fixed_point):
    mtrans.Transform.__init__(self)
    self.input_dims = self.output_dims = 2
    self.has_inverse = False
    self.trans = trans
    self.fixed_point = np.array(fixed_point).reshape(1, 2)

def transform_non_affine(self, values):
    fp = self.trans.transform(self.fixed_point)
    values = np.array(values)
    if values.ndim == 1:
        return fp.flatten() + values
    else:
        return fp + values
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I would have never found that, I don't think it is mentioned in the api docs.

Comment: Nice solution, however, the transformation is not called upon zooming/panning, so the cross doesn't remain at the desired position in data coordinates. Any idea how to solve that?